# Registering COM objects on Windows 7

Tags: visual-studio-2008, com, windows-7

I am running Visual Studio in none administrative mode under Windows 7. Everything works well except for the COM registration every time i build my project. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

You need amin privileges for the registration. Note however that the object needs to be registered only once, not every time you build it.

Just fire up a command prompt with admin privilege and type `regsvr32 path/my.dll`.
If it's an exe, you usually register it using `path/my.exe /regserver` but that depends on your framework.

Of course, if you add new objects to your COM DLL/EXE, you need to register it again.

Also, if you want to switch from debug to release build, you'll need to re-register the correct version (debug or release) since they stand in different directories.

Comment: Yes, this is what i've been doing. I was hoping there's a cleaner solution

Answer (score 2):

Right-click on Visual Studio and choose "Run as administrator" when starting it.